# What are the basic implementations that make a network secure from the inside\outside?

Tags: network, firewalls, access-control, hardening

Would you consider the following to be "basic hardening items" for network equipment and servers?

- VLANs
- Access Control (such as NTFS permissions)
- Patch Management System
- Host Firewall
- Anti-Virus

What is the minimal protection needed to segment my internal network from the DMZ and the outside? Is having a WAF, assuming you're dealing with web applications, and default denies, with tightly confined rules, on the firewalls sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic principles for making a network secure are 'defence in depth' - that is, you want to put as many things between your 'crown jewels' and potential attackers as you can - and 'minimal surface area' - that is, you expose as little as possible to attack.

To get there; your list of basics is pretty good at addressing 'defence in depth', though you may want the ability to blacklist/whitelist applications.

You should have a look at minimal surface areas - turn off admin privileges, unused services, blacklist any application running outside of c:\windows, c:\program files, etc., block executables on USB, turn off web access on machines that don't need it, etc.

Finally, the Australian DSD guide at http://www.dsd.gov.au/publications/Top_35_Mitigations_2012.pdf is a very good 'checklist' for this sort of thing - start at the top and work down.

Comment: Very nice link to the OZ DSD, I'm printing some dozens of A3 copies of that, cheers!

Comment: May also be interested in http://www.dsd.gov.au/publications/Catch_Patch_Match.pdf (and http://www.dsd.gov.au/videos/catch-patch-match.htm) if you're communicating to non-IT people.